# npm express "hello world" middleware error

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

node --version
v0.10.26

npm --version
1.4.3

I followed this: http://expressjs.com/guide.html

which has this code

```
    var express = require('express'),
    app = express();
app.use(express.logger());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello World');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

I try  'node app.js' in the terminal and I got this error:

```
Error: Most middleware (like logger) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.

    at Function.Object.defineProperty.get 

(/home/mike/node/helloworld/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:89:13)

    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mike/node/helloworld/app.js:4:17)

    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)

    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)

    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)

    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)

    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)

    at startup (node.js:119:16)

    at node.js:902:3
```

I'm new with express, any help will be welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: The error pretty much sums it up, `express.logger()` is no longer included, you have to install it separately.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The first line tells it all:

> Error: Most middleware (like logger) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.

Looking at https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware we can see that `express.logger` has been replaced with [`morgan`](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan).

```
var logger = require('morgan');
app.use(logger); //replaces your app.use(express.logger());
```

Remember to `npm install morgan` and/or add it to your `package.json`

Comment: in the last line I had to write  
"app.use(logger());" 
to make it work.

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem. I ran the below from the directory where my node js file was

```
npm install --save morgan
```

Using above command adds the dependency to your package.json.

Once package added, logger can now be used as

```
logger = require('morgan');
app.use(logger('dev'));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Most middleware (like logger) is no longer bundled with Express and
>   must be installed separately. Please see
>   https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware

express.logger('dev') is **removed** from express module.

use logger like **morgan**.

```
var morgan = require("morgan");
app.use(morgan('combined'));
```

for more details on morgan checkout the below link
[morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan)

Comment: Should be app.use there instead of app.user.

Answer (score 1):

You need a previous version:

```
npm install express@3.0.0
```