# How I can integrate an xmpp server into a node js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to combine 3 node js servers in one.

- In first server I have app server.
- In the second one I have node-xmpp-server ,
- and in the last one node-xmpp-bosh server.

I want to integrate the last two server in application server.How can I do this?I've tried with `express.vhost` but I have received an error

> like this : most middleware like vhost is no longer bundled with express and most be installed separately.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you run "npm install vhost" in the root of the app server? https://github.com/expressjs/vhost#install

Comment: Yes!I've installed it!

Comment: Okay, added an answer that should guide you towards the solution you need.

Answer (score 0):

After comment below explaining that you want all 'apps' to start at the same time, I suggest that you start up all the apps using a single 'bootstrap' file passing through the ports that you want to listen on. See [this github repo](https://github.com/benwhite-deltas/test-express-multiple-apps) for a very simple example that starts up two express apps from a single file `index.js` by requiring in the individual files that do app-specific configuration.

You can attach anything you want to the individual apps `module.exports` that can allow you to control them all as a group from code in the parent bootstrap file.

---

For those looking for a solution to the error reported by the asker, the below details how to resolve the error reported; but doesn't solve the asker's problem

As per the [documentation on the express 3.x to 4.x changes](http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html#core-changes) and the answer to [this question (though the middleware is different)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121778/npm-express-hello-world-middleware-error) now that vhost is no longer bundled with express it must be `require`d and used separately - it doesn't register itself on the `express` instance you're using, so you can't use the `express.vhost` method anymore.

From [here](https://github.com/expressjs/vhost#using-with-connect-for-static-serving), these are the relevant lines:

```
var vhost = require('vhost')

//...

// add vhost routing to main app for mail
app.use(vhost('mail.example.com', mailapp))
```

Comment: ok..I will say in anther mode...i have bosh app that is running in localhost:5280..I have serverClient app that is running in localhost:5000..and mainApp that is running on localhost:3000.I want when i start main app to start the next two app(that running on 5000 and 5280)...

Comment: Okay - so to clarify - you have three previously separate apps that you've brought into one codebase, and you (when you start your app) want to listen on all ports simultaneously? The apps don't need to be connected in code if that is the case; If you want all the apps to be started by the same bootstrap file, just require in each file that starts each app in the main bootstrap/index.

Comment: I don't know how to do this...give me a small example please

Comment: See edit to answer that gives link to a github repository with such an example.